# HTTPS Connection gives Privacy error in Browser. - Caddy Server

Tags: go, https, caddy

After modifying my Caddyfile to try a recommendation on this platform...i still can't get an
HTTPS connection in my browser..Chrome keeps saying 
"`Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`"

Here's my Caddyfile :

`localhost:9000 {
    bind {$ADDRESS}
    proxy / 197.211.58.62:9000
    tls self_signed
}`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [caddy docs](https://caddyserver.com/v1/docs/tls#examples) says the "self-signed certificate [is stored] in memory (untrusted by browsers, but convenient for local development)".

You'd have to generate the self-signed certificate outside of caddy and add it like a regular certificate.

Here's a guide to do it on [Linux and MacOS](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self) or [Windows](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/generating-self-signed-certificates-on-windows-7812a600c2d8)

Config Example from the docs

```
tls ../cert.pem ../key.pem
```

This snippet assumes the keys are located one folder up

BTW All this should work with Caddy 2